# Determine whether $f_n(z)=nz^{\sqrt{n}}(1-z^{\sqrt{n}})$ converges pointwise

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Let $$f_n(z)=nz^{\sqrt{n}}(1-z^{\sqrt{n}})$$
on $E:=\{z:|z|<1\}$.
Does $f_n(z)$ converge pointwise?

I think that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)=0$$ but I am not sure how to formally show that, i.e. given $\epsilon$ and $z$, find $N$ such that etc. With $f_n'(z)$, I found that $\max f_n=f_n(2^{-1/\sqrt{n}})=n/4$, but I don't know how or if I need to incorporate this into the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $|z|<1$. One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\log\left(\left|nz^{\sqrt{n}}\right| \right)=\log n +\sqrt{n}\ln|z|=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}} +\ln|z|\right) \to -\infty
$$ giving
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|nz^{\sqrt{n}}\right|=0.
$$ Now, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|f_n(z)\right|= \left|nz^{\sqrt{n}}(1-z^{\sqrt{n}})\right|\leq \left|nz^{\sqrt{n}}\right| \to 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have: $|f_n(z)| \leq 2m^2a^m$ with $m = \sqrt{n}, a = |z|< 1$. Thus you can prove $m^2a^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$. Put $b = \dfrac{1}{a} > 1$, then $m^2a^m = \dfrac{m^2}{b^m}$,and using L'hospitale rule twice it converges to $0$.